# Wordpress gives the error "Something went wrong. Your change may not have been saved.(..)" when using the REMOTE_ADDR variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to set up the following - accessing a page from a specific IP will show a specific < div > that'd be hidden for anyone else accessing the page from a different IP.

Wordpress 5.2.2; I've tried a couple of ways to execute the following idea, but the general idea I had was to compare the REMOTE_ADDR with my handpicked address using an if statement, and then echo'ing the style to display the block I wanted (provided the address was the same). I also tried escaping PHP and executing the necessary CSS like that, but I had the same problem. I'm not an experienced programmer by any means, so I can only assume I'm making a mistake somewhere.

`if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'xx.xxx.xx.xxx' ) {
echo '<style>.elementor-element-6788e0e{display:block!important;}</style>';
}`

It's not necessarily the code that's not working - it actually serves its purpose, and the block is shown only when accessed through that IP. However, as soon as I put anything in between the if statement brackets, Wordpress barely functions.

"Something went wrong. Your change may not have been saved. Please try again. There is also a chance that you may need to manually fix and upload the file over FTP." - When saving PHP.

"Looks like something’s gone wrong. Wait a couple seconds, and then try again." - When saving CSS.

Adding menu items doesn't work, etc.

I'm hoping someone can educate me on the cause of these errors, or show me a more correct way of tackling the CSS problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: < div > in your layout file or in post body?

Comment: In the post body, sorry for not specifying.

Comment: You probably placed this somewhere where it gets executed with every single request - including AJAX requests that occur when specific data/settings get saved, and if the code making those expects a valid JSON response, that gets invalidated if you just output arbitrary HTML code in front of it. You should go look into WordPress’s Hook system, and try and find one that allows you to only make this output in the relevant situations. Or, do this from within a specific template file. (Then the style element won’t be in the head, but browsers really don’t care that much to begin with.)

Comment: Ah, but of course, that makes sense. Thanks a lot, I've fixed it, and it works as intended. New to stackoveflow, don't know how to mark this as answered, but cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Insert this function to functions.php to remove this div in every post, of couse, you can modify this function as you want:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {
  return preg_replace('#<div class="elementor-element-6788e0e">(.*?)</div>#', '', $content);
}, 0);
```

Or using this in post.php file with only:

```
return preg_replace('#<div class="elementor-element-6788e0e">(.*?)</div>#', '', $content);
```